# Wiping old iPhone without touch or me.com?

Tags: iphone

I want to sell an old iPhone 3G for a few bucs... But I have a problem: the touch screen of the phone is broken and the phone has no internet-connectivity.

Is there any chance to delete the content on the phone? I can still make backups with iTunes.

Thanks for help :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can connect it to a PC/Mac, you can fully restore the phone using iTunes.

http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1414?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US

Comment: Wow... That was simple... And a *d'oh* to myself.

Answer (score 0):

DFU Mode can reset the device. Open iTunes on your computer. Connect iPhone to computer with USB cable. Make sure your iPhone is powered off.  Then hold both the Home and Power buttons, after exactly 10 seconds release the Power Button but keep holding the Home button until iTunes recognizes iPhone in Recovery Mode.  Sometimes around 20 seconds.

If the iPhone screen is black or blank this is DFU Mode. Click the Restore button in iTunes. DFU Mode can be difficult to enter sometimes, so just keep trying.